# How to generate random numbers in a thread safe way with OpenMP

Tags: c++, multithreading, random, openmp

Before parallelization, I was creating one `default_random_engine` object outside the loop since creating such objects isn't cheap. And I was reusing it inside the loop.

When parallelizing with `OpenMP`, I noticed that `uniform_dist(engine)` takes a mutable reference to the random engine which I assume isn't thread safe.
The program isn't crashing but I worry about its correctness.

I assume that `random_device` is thread safe so I could just move the definition of `default_random_engine` inside the loop but I don't want to create a random engine object every iteration since I read that that isn't cheap.

I think that an other way would be to create an array (of size: the number of threads) of `default_random_engine` objects and use OpenMP functions to select the right object at the start of each iteration based on thread ids.

Is there a better way?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int N = 1000;
    vector<int> v(N);
    random_device r;
    default_random_engine engine(r());

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
         uniform_int_distribution<int> uniform_dist(1, 100);
         // Perform heavy calculations
         v[i] = uniform_dist(engine); // I assume this is thread unsafe
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you need a separate generator instance for every thread.

Comment: Check slide 132 on... http://openmp.org/mp-documents/omp-hands-on-SC08.pdf

Comment: take a look at `jump` for xoroshiro128+ (http://xoroshiro.di.unimi.it/xoroshiro128plus.c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the actual code passes the random engine to many functions (Each generating integers and real numbers from different distributions), I went with the array of generator per thread because it imposes least changes to the code base:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    random_device r;
    std::vector<std::default_random_engine> generators;
    for (int i = 0, N = omp_get_max_threads(); i < N; ++i) {
        generators.emplace_back(default_random_engine(r()));
    }

    int N = 1000;
    vector<int> v(N);

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        // Get the generator based on thread id
        default_random_engine& engine = generators[omp_get_thread_num()];
        // Perform heavy calculations
        uniform_int_distribution<int> uniform_dist(1, 100);
        v[i] = uniform_dist(engine); // I assume this is thread unsafe
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Keep in mind that this code assumes that the function `omp_set_num_threads` never gets called in the program. If that was to happen, it will be possible for threads to get numbers (`omp_get_thread_num()`) greater than the old `omp_get_max_threads()` which would cause buffer overflow bugs.

And sadly, this solution assumes an implementation detail which is not required by the standard [as explained in this other comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37307627/how-can-i-get-the-maximum-number-of-openmp-threads-that-may-be-created-during-th/37309280#comment62153145_37309280).