# How can I get the maximum number of OpenMP threads that may be created during the whole execution of the program?

Tags: openmp

I want to create one global array of objects (One object per possible thread spawned by `OpenMP`) and reuse it throughout the program. Each thread will read its number using `omp_get_thread_num` and use it to index into the array.

How can I get the maximum number of `OpenMP` threads that may be created during the whole execution of the program?

The documentation of [`omp_get_max_threads`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp/omp_005fget_005fmax_005fthreads.html#omp_005fget_005fmax_005fthreads) says that this function is specified to return a value which is specific to the particular parallel region where it was invoked

> `omp_get_max_threads` – Maximum number of threads of parallel region
>
> **Description:** Return the maximum number of threads used for the current parallel region that does not use the clause num_threads.

Whereas the wording of [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62akecca.aspx) implies that the value returned by `omp_get_max_threads` outside a parallel region is the same value that would be returned in any other point.

> `omp_get_max_threads`
>
> Returns an integer that is equal to or greater than the number of threads that would be available if a parallel region without num_threads were defined at that point in the code.

Which one of them is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no maximum number.

Technically OpenMP defines an *internal control variable* called `nthreads-var` (see [OpenMP 4.5](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/openmp-4.5.pdf) 2.3.3) that is sort of the default number of threads. You read it with `omp_get_max_threads`, you set it with `omp_set_num_threads` (an unfortunate naming glitch), and you override it with an explicit `num_threads` clause.

So you will have to write your code such that it can cope with an unexpectedly number of threads, e.g. by predefining the array up to `omp_get_num_threads()` and lazily resizing it if more threads arrive. Or take a reasonable guess and check the index bounds on each access.

Comment: Thanks, so I understand that if I guarantee that `omp_set_num_threads` is never called in the program, I can rely on `omp_get_max_threads()` never changing. Right?

Comment: Practically, yes. But strictly following the standard, this is implementation defined. Since OpenMP 3.1, `nthreads-var` is a list - and the functions only refer to the first element. If there are more than one elements in the list, the tail is used in nested regions. Since the initialization of the list is implementation defined, an implementation could initialize the list like `[2,4]`. I doubt / hope that would ever happen.